# I cannot compile .cpp file in my macOS 10.14 anywhere but a directory that is generated by IDE project, such as Xcode or CLion

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, g++, clang++

I am just trying to compile C++ code without using IDE, however I encountered the following error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>     "_main", referenced from:
>        implicit entry/start for main executable
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

What I was testing is just a simple hello world program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  cout << "Hello World! ";
  cout << "I'm a C++ program";
}
```

Both g++ and clang++ do not work with the same error. Compiling can be done successfully within a directory that is generated by CLion though. I guess maybe it is because the IDE could configure everything about compiler by itself? Is there something wrong with any path setting with my C++ compilers? Anyone can help on this? Thank you so much.

Comment: What is the exact command-line command you ran?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out...
It turned out that I forgot to save the .cpp file before compile in Visual Studio Code...I should have turned on the autosave.
What a stupid mistake...